# Why didn't Dumbledore Apparate to Slughorn's doorstep?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

In *Half Blood Prince* Harry and Dumbledore walk to Slughorn's hiding place.  Why didn't Dumbledore Apparate directly to his doorstep instead of walking there?

Comment: ...it's impolite?

Comment: Slughorn was old. Didn't want to give him a heartattack. But yes, courtesy. As mentioned in answers below, Harry actually asks D about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two reasons:

First, Dumbledore wanted to have time to talk to Harry about his scar.

> “So tell me, Harry,” said Dumbledore. “Your scar . . . has it
> been hurting at all?”
> Harry raised a hand unconsciously to his forehead and
> rubbed the lightning-shaped mark.
> “No,” he said, “and I’ve been wondering about that. I
> thought it would be burning all the time now Voldemort’s
> getting so powerful again.”
> He glanced up at Dumbledore and saw that he was
> wearing a satisfied expression.

Second, It would have been rude:

> “Professor, why couldn’t we just Apparate directly into
> your old colleague’s house?”
> “Because it would be quite as rude as kicking down the
> front door,” said Dumbledore. “Courtesy dictates that we
> offer fellow wizards the opportunity of denying us entry.

While here Dumbledore is referring to apparating inside, it is clear this applies to also apparating onto one's doorstep, especially Slughorn.

Additionally (this is not explicit in the book): It seems to me that Dumbledore needed to cajole Slughorn into the appointment. Part of that cajoling includes allowing Slughorn the feeling he could say no, which means allowing Slughorn to maintain an appearance of being able to hide.

Comment: I would add a third reason: Slughorn used a Muggle house in a Muggle village. They might have been seen Apparating by a neighbour.

Comment: @Demosthenes that is a great reason. can I add it to my answer, or would you like to write it as your own?

Comment: Please go ahead and list all possible reasons in one answer.